# How to get image in SQL Server into a Visual Studio PictureBox

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
var aa = from employee in db.employees where employee.Employee_ID == int.Parse(l_id.Text) select employee.piture;
pictureboc1.Image = aa.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Not sure if storing a picture in db is a good idea (actually, I believe this a bad one), but I bet your `employee.piture` column is BLOB, so `aa.FirstOrDefault()` is a `byte[]`. You need to convert it to `System.Drawing.Image`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an good option to store images in database. An alternative is storing images in a file server and keep an id for images, store id in the database. Retrieve images when required with the use of id and file server

The file-system is the most flexible and performance wise good.

Average row - may consume a lot of memory if you store images in BLOB format. And your files might be locked often depending on the size / rate of files you are storing there due to table-locks .

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FileStream on SQLServer for storing binary data as byte[] (image, etc.)